# Redis info commandstat output

Tags: redis

On executing the command :
    'redis-cli info commandstat' 
redis gives commandstat grouped for certain commands like **cmdstat_command and cmdstat_cluster**. What do they mean?

Answer (score 1):

Each entry in the `commandstats` section of the [`INFO`](http://redis.io/commands/info) command corresponds to a Redis command, and the number of times it was called since server startup or the last call to `CONFIG RESETSTAT`. These two entries correspond to calls to the [`COMMAND`](http://redis.io/commands/command) and [`CLUSTER`](http://redis.io/commands/cluster) commands, respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the reply